# Create Accumulate function on Drools Decision table

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

I am trying to create accumulate function condition on Decision table. Please help me that How to create on Decision table.

My accumulate rule function is

```
when 

$i : Double(doubleValue >  1000 ) from accumulate( Product($productQty:quantity),sum($productQty))

then

System.out.println( "The quantity is exceeded more than 1000 and the total value is  " + $i );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a column

```
rows
n      condition
n+1    $i : Double() from accumulate( Product($productQty:quantity),sum($productQty))
n+2    doubleValue > $param
n+3    add quantitities and check
n+4    1000
```

Two comments.

1. This is not well-suited for decision tables unless you plan to check for different ranges of the accumulated value.
2. Why do you use `double` for counting what is, most likely, integral quantities? I'd be surprise if the accumulated stock exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE. In short: use `Number` in the pattern and `intValue` in the constraint.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I got stuck at one place. If i want to sum of quantity with condition (ie $i : Number( ) from accumulate ( Product( $productQty:quantity, productName in ( "ProductA", "ProductB" ) ),sum($productQty))). The conditions value will get from rules row

Comment: I tried with $i : Number( ) from accumulate ( Product( $productQty: quantity, productName in ( "$1", "$2" ) ),sum($qty))).
But It's not working . Please help me to solve the issue

Comment: See my comment #1 in my answer. Using accumulate with conditions and consrtaint parameters to be inserted from the spreadsheet cells is not something you can handle with Drools decision tables. Use technical rules.